# How to count the number of rows within an Angular grid in Protractor test?

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, angular-grid

As part of a Protractor test on my Angular app, I am trying to count the number of rows in an [Angular Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/).

I am able to count the number of columns using `ag-header-cell` as each header / column has that CSS class:

```
let list = element.all(by.css('div.ag-header-cell'));
expect(list.count()).toBe(3);
```

But when I try to apply the same logic to the rows within the grid, 0 rows are being returned.

My code:

```
let list = element.all(by.css('div.ag-row'));
expect(list.count()).toBe(10);
```

My error message: *Expected 0 to be 10.*

As you can see from the below snippet, several divs have the `ag-row` CSS class, so I don't know why it's not picking up any:

[image: codeSnippet]

Comment: Maybe the `div.ag-row`'s get painted at a small time later and your code queries the dom too early. Try putting a pause of 5 seconds, then `let list = element.all(bycss('div.ag-row'))`. If this passes, then you know the grid is getting painted at a later point in time and you need to take care of this somehow. For unit tests (where I have this issue), I return a promise that resolves only when the whole grid is painted (by checking that number of rows and columns is good in the dom). Once this promise resolves, I continue with my assertions.

Comment: Hi @AliF50, before I saw your comment, I just tried using `browser.sleep(5000)` to see if that was the issue & that managed to show the correct count. I'll add a promise like you've mentioned above to deal with this. Thanks a lot!